# How to update specific column if it's unchanged in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

Given a table with following columns:
(
Id int pk, Count1 int, Count2 int, Count3 int
)

For a row, I want to update(inc/dec) only Count2 if Count2 hasn't changed, regardless if other columns changed.

eg:
if i read (Count1, Count2, Count3):

(1,4,5) I want to increment/decrement Count2 in case it's ( * , 4 , * ) but not if its ( * , 3 , * )

I could write a raw sql query, but I want to know if it's possible without.

Update:

The result should be equivalent of a query:

```
UPDATE Table SET Count2 = @NewValue WHERE Count2 = @OriginalValue
```

and return nr of affected results/throw exception if row wasn't updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the change tracker to compare the original value with the current value in the column.

```
var entry = context.ChangeTracker.Entries<EntityType>()
    .First(e => e.Id = 22);  // find your entity

// compare the value entry.OriginalValues to the current value
```

Then you can set the entity state to whatever you need.

Comment: The problem is related to db concurency, what happens if after I read entity from db some other user changes that count2; this solution would only detect if the field is changed in current context, not for concurent user connections.

Comment: You'd get an exception because EF uses optimistic concurrency. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592904.aspx  http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: yes, except that with the way optimistic concurrency is implemented any column change would trigger that exception and that is what i'm trying to avoid. If after I read the entity from db another user changed Count1 for example, but i just want to update Count2 I don't want to get concurency exception since count2 has the same value.